# Prevent enumitem from adjusting vertical space around quote and center environments in KOMA-script classes

Tags: spacing, lists, koma-script, enumitem

In documents that use KOMA-script classes (like `scrartcl`), loading the `enumitem` package with no options alters the vertical space around environments that use `list` internally, such as `quote` or `center`:

[image: Side by side comparison]

**How can I prevent `enumitem` from automatically changing vertical spacing for nested lists?**  I only want to use it to adjust horizontal margins.

MWE (comment out the `enumitem` package)

```
\usepackage[papersize={8cm,8cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{itemize}
\item Some item
  \begin{center}
    Some centered text
  \end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[ignoredisplayed]{enumitem}`  should work.

Comment: It does, thanks!  But do you know why the issue affects only KOMA-script?